# Multi threading in command line possible?

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command

I'm using the following command to check the whois information from a list of domains in a text file and then output any lines that contain an email to a new file:

```
for i in $(cat testdomains.txt); do whois $i| egrep [a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]; done >> results.txt
```

Is there any way to speed this up by checking more than one domain at a time?  For example, right now it is going from one domain to the next checking the information. Is there anything I could change in the command to make it check 50 domains at a time?

Answer (score 3):

With `&`, you can run any command in background (so in parallel) :

```
for i in $(< testdomains.txt); do
    whois "$i" | egrep '[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]' &
done >> results.txt
```

### Note

- If you put the control operator `&` at the end of a command, e.g. `command args &`, the shell executes the command in the background in a *subshell*. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0. Pid of the last backgrounded command is available via the special variable `$!`
- every `&` do a `fork(2)` in the background
- see [How do I wait for several spawned processes?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/108)

Comment: So that will check all of the domains at the same time?

Comment: @syf101 : Yes, that's it =)

Comment: Hmmm that is very useful to know actually, but I don't think my server would be able to handle that.  It would cause it to be checking tens of thousands of domains at the same time and crash :/  But if it's possible to do something like check 50 or so at a time and then maybe remove them once checked and continue.  Whatever you think would be the fastest

Comment: See my new note about "waiting for several process"